# Creating an array of 1:N in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This is a super simple question and I haven't yet been able to piece together a solution I want from previous answers.

I have N images on a sheet and simply wish to group them. Normally I would use:

`Sheets("Mail").Shapes.Range(Array(1,2,3,4,5)).Group`

but obviously this doesn't work if I want to go from 1 to N. I am currently trying:

```
For i = 0 To Y / 33
  ReDim Preserve test(i)
  test(i) = i
Next i

Sheets("Mail").Shapes.Range(Array(test())).Group
```

But I am not sure how to use my test object to replicate the format I used in the non-general case. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't your statement simply be `Sheets("Mail").Shapes.Range(test).Group` because `test` is already an array?  (And you need to change `test(i) = i` to `test(i) = i + 1`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a function, returning numeric arrays from **M** to **N** :

```
Public Function ReturnArrayAtoB(ByVal M As Long, ByVal N As Long) As Variant

    Dim lngCounter  As Long
    Dim arrReturn   As Variant

    ReDim arrReturn(N - M)

    For lngCounter = 0 To N - M
        arrReturn(lngCounter) = M + lngCounter
    Next lngCounter

    ReturnArrayAtoB = arrReturn

End Function
```

This is how you call it:

```
arrA = ReturnArrayAtoB(1, 5)
arrB = ReturnArrayAtoB(10, 12)
```

The first one returns `Array(1,2,3,4,5)`
and the second one returns `Array(10,11,12)`

Comment: Does this accept integer variables as arguments? I am would like to use this in the form `ReturnArrayAtoB(1,Y)` where Y is an integer that was defined earlier in the code. Currently it gives a Type Mismatch.

Comment: @alex1stef2 - change the long in my code to integer everywhere, it should work.

Comment: I haven't tried YowE3K's version but simply changing the longs to integers worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @alex1stef2 - the version with `ByVal` accepts both Integer and Long now

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, there is a more concise way to create contiguous arrays using the `Evaluate` function:

```
Public Function ReturnArrayWithEvaluate(ByVal M As Long, ByVal N As Long) As Variant
    Dim vArr1 As Variant
    vArr1 = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("ROW(" & M & ":" & N & ")"))
    ReturnArrayWithEvaluate = vArr1
End Function
```

As Vityata observes in the comments, this method comes with some shortcomings:

- It fails if `N > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`
- It has limited portability, as `ROWS` does not exist in other VBA versions, such as `Access VBA`
- Performance-wise it is not worth it

I report hereby some tests, in which I vary the value of `N` from `10,000` to `1,000,0000` and run the two methods (for `M=1`).

**Benchmark setup**

Functions used:

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Public Function ReturnArrayWithEvaluate(ByVal M As Long, ByVal N As Long) As Variant
    Dim vArr1 As Variant
    vArr1 = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Evaluate("ROW(" & M & ":" & N & ")"))
    ReturnArrayWithEvaluate = vArr1

End Function

Public Function ReturnArrayAtoB(ByVal M As Long, ByVal N As Long) As Variant

    Dim lngCounter  As Long
    Dim arrReturn   As Variant

    ReDim arrReturn(N - M)

    For lngCounter = 0 To N - M
        arrReturn(lngCounter) = M + lngCounter
    Next lngCounter

    ReturnArrayAtoB = arrReturn

End Function

Sub test()
    Dim M As Long, N As Long
    Dim lTicks As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long, lStep As Long, lCnt2 As Long

    Dim vArrReturn As Variant
    Dim vArrResults As Variant

    M = 1
    N = 10000
    lStep = 9900 / 2
    lCnt2 = 1

    ReDim vArrResults(1 To 99 * N / lStep + 1)

    For lCnt = N To N * 100 Step lStep
        lTicks = GetTickCount
        vArrReturn = ReturnArrayAtoB(M, lCnt)
        vArrResults(lCnt2) = GetTickCount - lTicks
        lCnt2 = lCnt2 + 1
    Next lCnt
    Range("B2").Resize(lCnt2 - 1, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(vArrResults)
    lCnt2 = 1
    For lCnt = N To N * 100 Step lStep
        lTicks = GetTickCount
        vArrReturn = ReturnArrayWithEvaluate(M, lCnt)
        vArrResults(lCnt2) = GetTickCount - lTicks
        lCnt2 = lCnt2 + 1
    Next lCnt
    Range("C2").Resize(lCnt2 - 1, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(vArrResults)
End Sub
```

**Results**

The horizontal axis shows `N` and the vertical axis the time used by each method.

[image: Looping vs Evaluate Ticks, for different <code>N</code>]

<del>For large arrays, evaluate is faster than looping.</del>

The assertion that `Evaluate` is faster than looping is actually incorrect!

On average, the two methods consume about the same time:

```
-- Average Looping is 57 ticks
-- Average Evaluate is 62 ticks
-- Median ticks are 62 for both methods
```

Overall, I think sticking to looping is probably a better option.

Comment: Good shout. I've used this and this approach does provide much better performance then looping.. hence the +1

Comment: It has two drawbacks - drawback 1 - it works only in Excel (no Access etc) and drawback two - the second test with `Large N/M ratio` is wrong, but you did not notice - 10 million should give an error, if you are using rows in Excel. Take a look at the array that you receive - it should be Error 2015.

Comment: @Zac - read my comment and check your code again, it is dangerous to use it.

Comment: And last but not least - for the optimal usage of 2^16 times looping is way faster than using Evaluate.

Comment: @Vityata Thanks for the tips - I have revised the post with extra experiments and notes. The code should be reproducible, so if you could double check the results it would be great!